# Failed to compile ./src/App.js Line 12:9: 'root' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, variables, d3.js, undefined

new to React! I am building a React application, which is currently using a d3.js  as shown below. I am displaying the results in a ag-grid. Now I have been told that the id root is not recognize and they want me to find a way to  resolve. How can I possibly do that?

What I am using so far is this:
*the id root is not recognize.*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import BarChart from './BarChart';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [12, 5, 6, 6, 9, 10],
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    id: root
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BarChart data={this.state.data} width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**please i need help**

Comment: How did you create this project? Also can you check in `index.html` file do you have `<div id="root"></div>` and if you don't find it please add it inside `<body>` tag of the html

Comment: in your piece of code `root` is a variable. There is no definition for that variable. That's why it says `undefined`. Are you sure you don't want to say `id: 'root'`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There should be index.js file in which you need to render your App Component:

```
ReactDOM.render(<AppRoot />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then in index.html, please confirm you are doing the following:

```
<body>
 <div id="root">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 12:9:  'root' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed